# Change email credentials when looping smtp python

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I am working with the below code to send emails to customer and as you guys know there is daily sending limits set by different companies.
What I want to achieve is to change email credentials before reaching limit but continue with the recipient list.
For example: I have 5 email credentials each email id will 50 emails and will change automatically.

Code I work with:

```
import smtplib 
  
 
li = ["xxxxx@gmail.com", "yyyyy@gmail.com"] 
  
for dest in li: 
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
    s.starttls() 
    s.login("sender_email_id", "sender_email_id_password") 
    message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
    s.sendmail("sender_email_id", dest, message) 
    s.quit()
```

Comment: Are you always sure to have enough gmail ID credentials to cover your customer list? In this example (5 credentials), you will be unable to email over 250 clients. Is it necessary that the first 50 clients be emailed from the first credentialset? or can each credential set email /any/ 50 clients?

Comment: lose the cruft in your language and provide the error information with a minimal example to reproduce error.

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the destination in its list, and transform that into an index into the credentials list.

```
for i, dest in enumerate(li):
    if i//50 >= len(credentials):
        print("Ran out of credentials")
        break
    creds = credentials[i//50]
    // use credentials to send mail
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a generator `nextcred` to loop over the credentials in a list until you have sent all the messages.  It wraps back to the first pair after you have looped over the whole list.

We use one pair to send 50 messages, then log out and back in with the next pair of credentials.

```py
import smtplib 


def nextcred():
    credentials = [('user', 'password'), ('plugh', 'xyzzy'), ('alfred', 'what me worry?')]
    while True:
        for tup in credentials:
            yield tup

li = ["xxxxx@gmail.com", "yyyyy@gmail.com"] 

cred = nextcred()
s = None

for idx, dest in enumerate(li):
    if (idx % 50) == 0:
        if s:
            s.quit()
        account, passw = next(cred)
        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
        s.starttls() 
        s.login(account, passw)

    message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
    s.sendmail("sender_email_id", dest, message) 

s.quit()
```

As an aside, I hope you are not really constructing your SMTP messages by pasting together strings.  The Python `email` library takes care of a mound of corner cases and complications which are hard to get right and impossible to guess how to solve if you are not intimately familiar with SMTP and MIME.

Answer (score 0):

```
clients = ["xxxxx@gmail.com", "yyyyy@gmail.com"]
chunk_size = 50
chunks = (clients[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0,len(clients), chunk_size))

creds = [("sender_email_id_1", "sender_email_id_password_1"), ("sender_email_id_2", "sender_email_id_password_2")]

for i,chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    try:
        user, pw = creds[i]
    except IndexError:
        print("Ran out of credentials")
        raise
    for client in chunk:
        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
        s.starttls() 
        s.login(user, pw) 
        message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
        s.sendmail(user, client, message) 
        s.quit()
```

If you'd rather not throttle yourself, but would like to keep trying to send as many emails as possible:

```
clients = ["xxxxx@gmail.com", "yyyyy@gmail.com"]
creds = [("sender_email_id_1", "sender_email_id_password_1"), ("sender_email_id_2", "sender_email_id_password_2")]

for cred,client in zip(itertools.cycle(creds), clients):
    user, pw = creds
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
    s.starttls() 
    s.login(user, pw) 
    message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
    s.sendmail(user, client, message) 
    s.quit()
```